# How to toggle Vuetify Carousel component right/left arrows on and off

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I want to dynamically control the visibility of the `(<)` and `(>)` arrows in the [Vuetify carousel component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/carousels#carousels).

For example, so that the final right arrow on the last item disappears, or so that I can use internal buttons or other interactivity within the `carousel-item` content to replace the buttons dynamically. (I know the `continuous` prop can do the simple end case).

The documentation for the `next-icon` and `prev-icon` prop is `bool` or `string` and the default says `$next`.

> ```
> Name    next-icon
> Type    boolean | string
> Default $next
> Description Icon used for the "next" button if show-arrows is true
> ```

I can make the icon button disappear by setting it to `false`, but `true` doesn't make it reappear.

I'm guessing the string value is the icon name (like `md-arrow-right`?) but the documentation doesn't say what the default is, and that doesn't work. I'm guessing that "off" is setting the prop to `false` and "on" is restoring it to the icon name.

I also don't understand what `$next` means, and this isn't explained in the page. It errors if you use that as a value. Everything else seems to evaluate to false.

I'm guessing it's something like this:

```html
<template>
  <v-carousel v-model="stepNo" :show-arrows="show.arrows" :next-icon="show.nextArrow" height="auto" light>
  <!-- ... -->
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => {
    return {
      stepNo: 0,
      show: {
        arrows: true,
        nextArrow: "md-arrow-right",
      },
    }
  },
  watch: {
    stepNo: function(newStep, oldStep) {
      // some logic here, for example
      this.nextArrow = (newStep === 4) ? "md-arrow-right" : false;
    },
  },
  //...
}
</script>
```

---

UPDATE

One of my mistakes was `md-arrow-right` should be `mdi-arrow-right` (missing the `i`), or actually `mdi-chevron-right` as noted by tony19. So I can now set it to a literal icon OK.

But setting it to `$next` or `$prev` still doesn't work - it displays either nothing, and empty circle, or a $ sign which is actually the word `$next`. And this seems to "break" the binding and setting it to a literal icon after this, fails until reloading the page.

```
<i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate material-icons theme--light" style="font-size: 36px;">$next</i>
```

Comment: I haven't used vuetify in a while but looking through the docs, have you tried setting the prop `continuous` to `false`?

Comment: @Liang-ShihLin yes I have, and that does provide the example of turning next off at the end, but I needed more control over them, like when an interactive carousel-item contains a button instead. Perhaps it was a bad example!

Comment: You want just to move next and prev if you press left and right arrow? Am I getting you right?

Comment: @V.Sambor No, I want to toggle the visibility/display of the buttons on and off, from within the code depending on which item is displayed (or other rules).

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can achieve the behavior you wanted without relying on documentation if it doesn't provide what you need.

Just inspect the `left` and `right` arrow of the carousel component and get the DOM Node by selector.
Then you are ready to do what you want with the elements.

For exemple:

```
const nextButton = document.querySelector('.v-window__next button');

const prevButton = document.querySelector('.v-window__prev button');
```

(Maybe instead of `document` you can use the `$el` inside your component)

Now you can do whatever you want with your elements.

To `show/hide` dynamically:

```
nextButton.style.display = 'None'; // Hide
nextButton.style.display = 'Block'; // Show
```

To `navigate`:

```
nextButton.click(); // Go next.
prevButton.click(); // Go prev.
```

`Vue` is just `JavaScript` at the end, no magic ;)

BTW, you could try this directly in the browser console on the [link](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/carousels#carousels) you provided for the carousel.

Comment: Yes you are right, this is the kind of thing I've been doing for many years, either native or then Prototype, JQuery, Dojo... etc! But I'm trying to be a good boy and not hack behind the scenes, and want to use Vue / Vuetify's API properly. I would worry this approach might break if they change their selectors or DOM structure in the next version.

Comment: That's true! But as far as they don't provide a way, either you wait for them to implement or you contribute yourself or you do things like this and you have to maintain for the future... :-|

Comment: DOM manipulation in Vue is not recommended, as that change could be undone when the Vue component is re-rendered.

Answer (score 1):

*The icon visibility should be restored when setting it to `$next` (as seen in demo code snippet below).*

#### About `$next`...

For all icons in the framework, Vuetify uses [`v-icon`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/icons#icons) to render the icon specified by name. Icon names are mapped to an iconset (default is [Material Design Icons](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/v2.2.8/packages/vuetify/src/services/icons/presets/mdi.ts)). The mapped icon names are identified by the `$` prefix, and [remapped](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/v2.2.8/packages/vuetify/src/util/helpers.ts#L217) during icon rendering.

For instance, the `mdi` preset maps [`$prev` to `mdi-chevron-left`](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/v2.2.8/packages/vuetify/src/services/icons/presets/mdi.ts#L13) and [`$next` to `mdi-chevron-right`](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/v2.2.8/packages/vuetify/src/services/icons/presets/mdi.ts#L14); and the `fa` (Font Awesome) preset maps [`$prev` to `fas fa-chevron-left`](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/v2.2.8/packages/vuetify/src/services/icons/presets/fa.ts#L13) and [`$next` to `fas fa-chevron-right`](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/v2.2.8/packages/vuetify/src/services/icons/presets/fa.ts#L14).

Literal icon names (without the `$` prefix) could also be explicitly used. For example, you could specify `mdi-arrow-expand-right` instead of `$next` in `v-icon`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      nextIcon: '$next',
      prevIcon: '$prev',
      nextIconEnabled: true,
      prevIconEnabled: true,
      colors: [
        'indigo',
        'warning',
        'pink darken-2',
        'red lighten-1',
        'deep-purple accent-4',
      ],
      slides: [
        'First',
        'Second',
        'Third',
        'Fourth',
        'Fifth',
      ],
    }
  },
  watch: {
    nextIconEnabled(nextIconEnabled) {
      if (nextIconEnabled) {
        this.nextIcon = this._lastNextIcon
      } else {
        this._lastNextIcon = this.nextIcon
        this.nextIcon = false
      }
    },
    prevIconEnabled(prevIconEnabled) {
      if (prevIconEnabled) {
        this.prevIcon = this._lastPrevIcon
      } else {
        this._lastPrevIcon = this.prevIcon
        this.prevIcon = false
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.controls {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.2.8/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.2.8/dist/vuetify.min.css">


<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div class="controls">
      <label>Toggle next-icon
        <input type="checkbox" v-model="nextIconEnabled">
      </label>
      <label>next-icon:
        <input v-model="nextIcon" placeholder="icon name"/>
      </label>
      <label>Toggle prev-icon
        <input type="checkbox" v-model="prevIconEnabled">
      </label>
      <label>prev-icon:
        <input v-model="prevIcon" placeholder="icon name"/>
      </label>
    </div>
    <v-carousel
      height="400"
      hide-delimiter-background
      :prev-icon="prevIcon"
      :next-icon="nextIcon"
    >
      <v-carousel-item
        v-for="(slide, i) in slides"
        :key="i"
      >
        <v-sheet
          :color="colors[i]"
          height="100%"
        >
          <v-row
            class="fill-height"
            align="center"
            justify="center"
          >
            <div class="display-3">{{ slide }} Slide</div>
          </v-row>
        </v-sheet>
      </v-carousel-item>
    </v-carousel>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: OK so I was on the right track - and my code should work, so it's a bug rather than lack of feature. When I set the next-icon both "$prev" or $next" and "md-arrow-right" but I get an empty circle, or a circle with a big dollar sign next to it.

Comment: Sorry I just realised I missed the `:next-icon` attribute binding to `show.nextArrow` when I formatted the question. It's updated now. But I will debug, now I know it should work.

Comment: Can you please explain where I should have been able to find about `$next` mapping, other than exploring the code? Just so I know in future where to get information from.

Comment: The Vuetify docs for [icon usage](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/icons#usage) refer you directly to the code to determine the mappings. See the last line of the usage paragraph: "For more information, view the default [icon preset values](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/tree/master/packages/vuetify/src/services/icons/presets)." I'm not aware of any other reference.

Comment: OK thanks I see that now. But I don't think I'd have made the connection to $prev even if I'd read this, the addition nor meaning of the dollar sign isn't explained anywhere. I hadn't thought of reading the icon docs when reading the carousel. I will in future put more effort to think about the sub-components.

Answer (score 0):

A simple typo in the icon name:

```
nextArrow: "md-arrow-right",
```

should be

```
nextArrow: "mdi-arrow-right",
```

I keep making this mistake because I get the icon names by searching https://materialdesignicons.com/ where the icon names do not have the `mdi-` prefix and I so often get it wrong when manually adding `md-` for just material design.

Answer (score 0):

There some ways to have more control over the **carousel component**

To programaticaly control if the arrows will be showed, you can delegate this to a variable

`continuous=false` will do the job hiding the arrows on the begining/end of the elements list

And to determine wich element will be active, you can use `v-model`

```
    <v-carousel
      :show-arrows=arrows
      :progress=false
      :continuous=false
      v-model="item"
      hide-delimiter-background
    >
      <v-carousel-item
        v-for="n in 15"
        :key="n"
      >
      <v-card>
            {{item}}
          <v-btn
            text
            @click="nextItem"
          >
            Next Item
          </v-btn>

          <v-btn
            text
            @click="showHideArrows"
          >
            showHideArrows
          </v-btn>

        </v-card>
      </v-carousel-item>
    </v-carousel>
```

`nextItem()`: will change the current active item

`showHideArrows()`: will toggle the arrow's state

```
   data: () => ({
      arrows: false,
      item: 0,
    }),

  methods: {
    nextItem() {
      console.log('next');
      this.item += 1;
    },
    showHideArrows() {
      this.arrows = !this.arrows;
      console.log(this.arrows);
    },
  },
```